# Is this model method locking up my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, sidekiq

My application is crashing really, really hard, and it appears to be related to the database. The application deals with lots and lots of data, and hundreds of simultaneous users. In an effort to speed up data loads, I am loading some records like this:

```
def load(filename)

  rc = Publication.connection.raw_connection
  rc.exec("COPY invoice_line_items FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER")

  # open up your CSV file looping through line by line and getting the line into a format suitable for pg's COPY...
  error = false
  begin
    CSV.foreach(filename) do |line|
      until rc.put_copy_data( line.to_csv )
        ErrorPrinter.print "  waiting for connection to be writable..."
        sleep 0.1
      end
    end
  rescue Errno => err
    User.inform_admin(false, User.me, "Line Item import failed with #{err.class.name} the following error: #{err.message}", err.backtrace)
    error = true
  else
    rc.put_copy_end
    while res = rc.get_result
      if (res.result_status != 1)
        User.inform_admin(false, User.me, "Line Item import result of COPY was: %s" % [ res.res_status(res.result_status) ], "")
        error = true
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I also have Sidekiq running with about 90 threads. Does this method of loading put an exclusive lock on that table? Is it possible that these jobs are running into each other? If they are, am I better off just doing inserts?

Comment: "crashing really, really hard" is evocative but not informative.  What actually happens?

Comment: The app servers stop responding completely. The database has tons of processes that don't appear to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` takes the same level of lock as `INSERT`. (It's missing from the [explicit locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) chapter, but visible in the source code). So whatever's giving you trouble, it's probably not that.

You should be looking at `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity` to see if anything's stuck on a lock. More info on other questions on SO or DBA.SE, the manual, and the PostgreSQL wiki.